# jquery- reverse nested icon's color just on click not for ever

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a nested icon and I want it's color become reversed on click.Using jQuery I can change colors but it changes forever while I want it to changes just on click!
HTML:

```
<div id="listSlider-right-icon">
            <i id="listSlider-right-arrow" class="fa fa-2x fa-square ">
                <i id="play-icon" class="fa fa-play"></i>
            </i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#listSlider-right-icon{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: green;
}
#listSlider-right-icon{
    right: 10%;
}


#listSlider-right-arrow i{
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0.6em;
    margin-left: -7px;
    color: white;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('#listSlider-right-arrow').click(function () {
        $(this).css('color', '#fff');
        $('#play-icon').css('color', '#01a89e');
    });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94ncv5o2/1/)

In addition, I was wondering if it's possible using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your jQuery to this :

```
$('#listSlider-right-arrow').mousedown(function () {
  $(this).css('color', '#fff');
  $('#play-icon').css('color', '#01a89e');
});
$('#listSlider-right-arrow').mouseup(function () {
  $(this).css('color', 'green');
  $('#play-icon').css('color', 'white');
});
```

`.mousedown` and `.mouseup` speak for themselves.

You also can add this to your CSS :

```
#listSlider-right-arrow:active {
  color: #fff;
}
#listSlider-right-arrow:active #play-icon {
  color: #01a89e;
}
```

This works because `#play-icon` is in `#listSlider-right-arrow`

Comment: Is it possible using css?

Comment: Try the `:active` CSS selector

Comment: I'm familiar with `:active` selector but my problem is if I select `#listSlider-right-arrow:active` how could I say change another element (`#play-icon`) while I select  `#listSlider-right-arrow:active`?

Answer (score 0):

so its color changes just the time you click it ?

Have a look at the `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` events which are the start and the end of a click.